# How can I set AUTO_INCREMENT for @PrimaryColumn()?

Tags: node.js, orm, typeorm

How can I set `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `@PrimaryColumn()`?

I know that `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` does this but I want to have ID from the `double` type.

Is it possible to have `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` with `double` type? if not have can I set `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `@PrimaryColumn()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class SomeWhat{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    public id: number;
....
```

For `double` ID, we can't use `AUTO_INCREMENT`. `AUTO_INCREMENT` is just available for `int` type.

- `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`

  We can set `AUTO_INCREMENT` at only `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` decorator.
  The below code is the declaration of the `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`.
  As you can see, we can use 2 types of strategy (increment, uuid).

  **(typeorm/decorator/columns/PrimaryGeneratedColumn.d.ts)**

  ```
  export declare function PrimaryGeneratedColumn(): Function;
  export declare function PrimaryGeneratedColumn(options: PrimaryGeneratedColumnNumericOptions): Function;
  export declare function PrimaryGeneratedColumn(strategy: "increment", options?: PrimaryGeneratedColumnNumericOptions): Function;
  export declare function PrimaryGeneratedColumn(strategy: "uuid", options?: PrimaryGeneratedColumnUUIDOptions): Function;
  ```
- `@PrimaryColumn`

  But in this `@PrimaryColumn`, there is no available strategy. This is just transforming the value to the primary key without generating.

  **(typeorm/decorator/columns/PrimaryColumn.d.ts)**

  ```
  export declare function PrimaryColumn(options?: ColumnOptions): Function;
  export declare function PrimaryColumn(type?: ColumnType, options?: ColumnOptions): Function;
  ```